# Create a new dataframe with binding columns from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a big data with 1000 of columns and lacs of record and I want to bind group of columns into one and create a new dataframe.

```
df <- mtcars

col1 <- cbind(c(rbind(df$mpg,df$cyl,df$disp)))
col2 <- cbind(c(rbind(df$wt,df$qsec)))
col3 <- cbind(c(rbind(df$vs,df$am,df$gear)))
```

The output should be like rbind mpg,cyl,disp etc. bind another group of columns and the create dataframe with all binded columns.

My dataframe also have NA in cells.

Comment: How are you choosing the columns, is it every nth column gets rowbinded?

Comment: so actually selecting columns can be varied sometimes nth column, sometime side by side columns , i want to give column names in c()

Comment: If it is different number of columns then you will end up with different number of rows? When you want to cbind col1, col2, col3 etc, they will not have the same number of rows.

Comment: ok got it , so in my case combining number of columns will be same like  group1<-c(col1,col2,col3)  group2<- c(col7,col9,col13)

Comment: so over all objective is to create data frame group1 and group 2......group 7
that's way i want to bind columns

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of columns per group, then subset using *lapply*, set the vector lengths the same for column binding.

```
df <- mtcars

#make groups of columns for subset for each group
grps <- list(g1 = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"),
             g2 = c("wt", "qsec"),
             g3 = c("vs", "am", "gear"))

#subset
l <- lapply(grps, function(i) unlist(mtcars[, i]))

#set the lengths the same, then cbind
mx <- max(lengths(l))
res <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, 
               lapply(l, function(i) {
                 length(i) <- mx
                 i }))
#reset rownames
rownames(res) <- NULL

head(res)
#     g1    g2 g3
# 1 21.0 2.620  0
# 2 21.0 2.875  0
# 3 22.8 2.320  1
# 4 21.4 3.215  1
# 5 18.7 3.440  0
# 6 18.1 3.460  1
```